# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when appium server is down

Tags: java, appium

I try to run an appium test but get an IllegalArgumentException when appium server is down:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set io.appium.java_client.MobileElement field pages.LaunchPage.loginSignupButton to org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d27c0df4
```

If appium server is running then i am not getting any exception.

This is how i find the element:

```
@AndroidFindBy(id = “com.recntrek.staging:id/tutorial_signup_tv”)
private MobileElement loginSignupButton;
```

I initialize the element on a different class (the super class) :

```
PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(abstractPlatform.getDriverWrapper().getDriver()),this);
```

Any idea why this is happen?

Thanks

Comment: How do you expect appium to work if it's down ? ..

Comment: I don't expect appium to work if it's down. I expect to get a different exception if appium is down. Why I get IllegalArgumentException?